# File rename in json to csv conversion in cmd

Tags: python, json, csv, batch-file

I am trying to run this python command through command prompt which is as follows:

```
python "C:\Users\Bhavik\Desktop\Plaid Conversions\json_to_csv.py" accounts "C:\Users\Bhavik\Desktop\New folder (2)\file.json" "C:\Users\Bhavik\Desktop\New folder (2)\file.csv"
```

where

- `C:\Users\Bhavik\Desktop\Plaid Conversions\json_to_csv.py` is where the python file is located
- `accounts` - is the root node where it starts to read records
- C:\Users\Bhavik\Desktop\New folder (2)\file.json - location of json file
- C:\Users\Bhavik\Desktop\New folder (2)\file.csv - destination path of csv

I am trying to automate this process by creating a batch file where it reads the file name by itself and renames the csv file created with respective file name.

Here is the code I am trying:

```
C:  
:loop  
cd c:/Windows/system32  
set dir1=C:\Users\Bhavik\Desktop\PC  

for /r %X IN ("%dir1%\*.json") DO (   
        python "C:\Users\Bhavik\Desktop\Plaid Conversions\json_to_csv.py" accounts "%%~XI" "C:\Users\Bhavik\Desktop\PC\test.csv"  
        var name= $(echo %nxX | cut -f 1 -d '.')  
        rename C:\Users\Bhavik\Desktop\PC\test.csv name.csv  
        )  

goto loop
```

Here I'm trying to set the directory and making it read the json file-name and use in the python command where json file destination needs to be provided.
But I'm facing some issues with it.

1. %%X was unexpected at this time.
2. File "C:\Users\Bhavik\Desktop\Plaid Conversions\json_to_csv.py", line 89, in 
       fp = open(json_file_path, 'r')
   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '%%~XI'
3. 'var' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
   operable program or batch file.

Hello guys,
I have worked on the code and reached to the following one:
C:
:loop
cd c:/Windows/system32
set dir1=C:\Users\Bhavik\Desktop\PC2

for %X IN ("%dir1%*.json") DO (
    set "filename1=%~nX"
        echo %filename1%
        python "C:\Users\Bhavik\Desktop\Plaid Conversions\json_to_csv.py" accounts "%X" "C:\Users\Bhavik\Desktop\PC2\test.csv"
        rename "C:\Users\Bhavik\Desktop\PC2\test.csv" "%filename1%.csv" )

goto loop

But the problem I'm facing now is, when I'm setting the filename it shows the first json file in the folder but the value it shows on echoing is the last json file and thats how it renames it. I assume that is because it parses through the entire folder and thats why the last file is echoed every time.

How can I make it read and echo one file at a time and rename it? Any suggestions?

Comment: 1. You need to double the `%` signs in `for` variables in batch files (`%%X` rather than `%X`). 2. `var name= $(...)` is not batch file syntax. 3. My telepathic capabilities are limited, so it is quite hard for me to tell what is wrong in your Python code, since you don't share it...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys,

I didn't think through. Here is what I did to get it working:

C:
:loop
cd c:/Windows/system32
set dir1=C:\Users\Bhavik\Desktop\PC2
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %X IN ("%dir1%*.json") DO (
        python "C:\Users\Bhavik\Desktop\Plaid Conversions\json_to_csv.py accounts "%X" "C:\Users\Bhavik\Desktop\PC2\test.csv"
        rename "C:\Users\Bhavik\Desktop\PC2\test.csv" "%~nX.csv" )

goto loop
Thanks